# Can you call an instance method when assigning a class variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I have some methods that contain lots of different combinations of the same logic. To clean it up, I would like to define each test just once.

```
class Sentence < ApplicationRecord

#Gathers options hash for sentence
def options
    { 
        pronoun: subject.pronoun,
        ...
        }
end

#gives auxiliary verb based on sentence options 
def aux
    third_person = ["he", "she", "it"].include?(options[:pronoun])

    aux = "does" if third_person #just an example 
    ...
end
...
```

This works fine, but I am trying to pull this out of the aux method to use in other methods.

```
#this works
@@third_person = ["he", "she", "it"].include?("he")
#this says that there is no options method
@@third_person = ["he", "she", "it"].include?(options[:pronoun])
```

Does anyone know, what I'm missing?

Comment: When we're talking about "cleaning things up", one thing you want to pay careful attention to is declaring unchanging, but throw-away arrays inside methods like this. Use a constant like `PREFIXES = %w[ he she it ]` and then use that array over and over. You could also use a regular expression if there's some ambiguity or performance concerns. Likewise, returning a temporary hash that's used once is very inefficient, especially if the hash never changes.

Comment: The context of the test code isn't clear. Where are you running that? Also why are you declaring class-style `@@` variables?

Comment: I agree with @tadman that you should separate the pronouns to constant variable. Also use `freeze` method so it cannot be modified. `PREFIXES = %w(he she it).freeze`

Comment: Ok, cool no problem with the constant because it won't be changing. I think I'm a bit confused with the class variable though. It doesn't seem like its capable of doin what I want. I have an instance of sentence. The options method gets the options for that instance. I want to define a test that uses an instance option once and have access to it from the other instance methods. I guess another instance method would be the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the instance method `options` on instance of class Sentence.

You have to call it this way:

```
sentence = Sentence.new
['he', 'she', 'it'].include?(sentence.options[:pronoun])
```

Comment: That's the right answer to my question, but now I realise that I was going about everything the wrong way. Thanks for the quick answers, it helped me rethink my code.